# How to become a good PKer in runescape?

Tags: runescape

I can get a membership and make a fresh new account if needed.

1. What stats / armor / weapons / spells are best for PKing?
2. Apart from the right stats and gear, what else is needed to get good at PKing?

Comment: Uh, why the downvote?

Comment: Because I'm assuming that by PKing you meant killing players on your own team as a form of "griefing". I was too hasty, however, not taking the time to read about pvp in runespace - my bad, sorry.

Comment: @oak you must be a skiller noob. L2PK

Answer (score 4):

Here are some general tips:

> 1. Only trust your closest
>      friends
> 2. Bring at least 1
>      or more people with you.
> 3. The default for a good team
>      is 1 ranger and 1 mage
> 4. Always have telegrab spells
>      ready, you never know!
> 5. Don't eat during a fight.
>      Chances are that while you're eating
>      all the food will be wasted! Eat
>      during running so the pker will have a
>      hard time catching you, and if your
>      smart, run south.
> 6. Make
>      sure to mix your teams up with mages,
>      rangers, and warriors to balance the
>      triangle.
> 7. Make sure your
>      team won't Pk you!
> 8. Have
>      your teleport spells ready so you wont
>      have to run all the way back or if
>      your really in trouble, teleport.
> 9. Remember teleport spell
>      restrictions are if your lower than
>      level 20 wilderness, you can teleport
>      any higher you're on thin ice.
> 10. If you can't teleport run for
>       at least 10 seconds while clicking on
>       logout.
> 11. If someone is
>       running, use ranged and magic. No
>       matter what your
>      level to ensure
>       that they won't logout.
> 12. If you're a mage or wizard,
>       remember to use ensnare magic.
> 13. Make a bait player, for
>       example: Make Stupid1 run into the
>       wilderness where there is most likely
>       to be a Pker. When he attacks him he
>       will have a skull making you have more
>       spoils!

Comment: What's the source for this quote?

Comment: @AER This comment is years late, but the quote was originally taken from a site which (according to the edit history) is no longer available in it's current form, and now redirects to a porn site. Good example  of why we like answers to quote the relevant part of a site instead of just linking off to another site.